# Highlights and contrast

Tags: discussion, design

On highlighted questions, usernames (the asker's name), and codeblocks on main, the background is very low-contrast. This is an issue on my laptop screen, which, if it's at the wrong angle, makes the highlight invisible. Is there some way to increase contrast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *could* just write that you shouldn't use [the cheapest hardware you can find outside of spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFT_LCD#Twisted_nematic_.28TN.29). This won't help you though. But I don't think the site design will get optimized for your case either.

There's a real solution of the Super User kind, however: **[userscripts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/userscripts)**. Install [greasemonkey](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey) (or your browser's equivalent) and override the colors shown to *you*.

Alternatively, many browsers allow specifying custom style sheets. You might be able (through use of good CSS selectors) to limit this to SU, or at least SE. [Here's](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3893) how I tried to help one guy with a similar issue on Meta Programmers using this approach.

Comment: As a side note: If you have some [issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ishihara_9.png) with color seeing, cheap TN panels allow changing your viewing angle to increase contrast enough to distinguish between colors. Try doing that with IPS panels.

Comment: It's a laptop, so changing the screen isn't exactly easy. +1 for userscripts, though.